# Cheap way to fix peeling clear coat?

Tags: paint, paint-scratches, paint-clearcoat

The coat on my car is peeling away something like as shown in following picture which I just pulled up from google as an example:

[image]

This is my first car and I have never done any car work myself before, so please explain all the steps, where can I find the items etc. as if you are explaining a layman.

1) I would like to know how can I fix this on my car to make it look more better and uniform with my car color which is ebony black.

2) Also, a slightly different but related question is how to repair small scratches on the car. Thanks.

Comment: What make, model, and year is the vehicle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the answer for part (1) :**

http://www.ehow.com/how_7809103_repair-peeling-clear-coat.html

or

http://www.ehow.com/how_5028554_fix-peeling-clear-coat-car.html

**This is the answer for part (2) :**

http://www.ehow.com/how_2136091_fix-minor-scratch-car.html

or

http://www.ehow.com/how_5309590_fix-scratches-car.html

or

http://www.ehow.com/how_5596574_fix-car-scratch.html

Answer (score 7):

The clear coat is peeling and there is no cheap do at home product that will yield satisfactory results.The hood needs to be professionally refinished.The minor scratches may come out with a rubbing compound that is applied like regular paste wax.

Answer (score 2):

Pressure wash to remove loose clear coat, brush on clear urethane varnish to seal the edges and replace the clear. I have done this on the cap on my pickup, and where edges are coming loose on our Taurus.

Comment: You are actually suggesting painting clear urethane with a brush? I would bet the OP is asking how to make this look better ... not sure brushing it on is going to make that happen. Yes, it will seal the paint, but aesthetically will look pretty raunchy.

Answer (score -1):

After reading what people did to their cars where clear coat was coming off, I used a good wax on mine.  It will seal it for awhile.